# Adding numbers in phone format

Tags: react-native

please help me i need help make a phone number input  for example if i input 1234567890 from phone-pad it should input like this (123)456-7890. here is my code

```
<TextInput
  placeholder='(123)456-7890'
  keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
  style={{
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  borderRadius: 10,
  padding: 10,
  fontSize: 18,
  marginTop:10,
  fontWeight:'bold'}}
  onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.onEnterText(TextInputValue)}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the input string before setting state. Something like this:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState('')

const formatPhoneNumber = (str) => {
  let numbers = str.replace(/\D/g, '')
  if (numbers.length > 6) {
    return '(' + numbers.substr(0, 3) + ') ' + numbers.substr(3, 3) + '-' + numbers.substr(6)
  } else if (numbers.length > 3) {
    return '(' + numbers.substr(0, 3) + ') ' + numbers.substr(3)
  } else if (numbers.length >= 1) {
    return '(' + numbers  
  }
  return numbers
}

return (
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder="(123) 456-7890"      
    placeholderTextColor="lightgrey"
    maxLength={"(123) 456-7890".length}
    onChangeText={(str) => setNumber(formatPhoneNumber(str))}
    value={number}
  />
)
```